# Wordpress Geocoding using direction or a map

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, google-maps-api-3, geocoding

I'm trying to make a Wordpress page where the user can point to a location by writing the adress or browsing a map`.

As you can see in the page (http://www.levinor.es/pruebas/pagina-ejemplo/) the map isn't loading and I don't know why... I checked the API Key, and the allowed domains (*.levinor.es/*) of the key... Please I need some help...

To do so I created this javascript (google-maps.js) and placed it in the script folder of my theme:

```
//Declaramos las variables que vamos a user
var lat = null;
var lng = null;
var map = null;
var geocoder = null;
var marker = null;

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
     //obtenemos los valores en caso de tenerlos en un formulario ya guardado en la base de datos
     lat = jQuery('#lat').val();
     lng = jQuery('#long').val();
     //Asignamos al evento click del boton la funcion codeAddress
     jQuery('#pasar').click(function(){
        codeAddress();
        return false;
     });
     //Inicializamos la función de google maps una vez el DOM este cargado
    initialize();
});

    function initialize() {

      geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

       //Si hay valores creamos un objeto Latlng
       if(lat !='' && lng != '')
      {
         var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
      }
      else
      {
        //Si no creamos el objeto con una latitud cualquiera como la de Mar del Plata, Argentina por ej
         var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.0625,-95.677068);
      }
      //Definimos algunas opciones del mapa a crear
       var myOptions = {
          center: latLng,//centro del mapa
          zoom: 15,//zoom del mapa
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP //tipo de mapa, carretera, híbrido,etc
        };
        //creamos el mapa con las opciones anteriores y le pasamos el elemento div
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

        //creamos el marcador en el mapa
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,//el mapa creado en el paso anterior
            position: latLng,//objeto con latitud y longitud
            draggable: true //que el marcador se pueda arrastrar
        });

       //función que actualiza los input del formulario con las nuevas latitudes
       //Estos campos suelen ser hidden
        updatePosition(latLng);


    }

    //funcion que traduce la direccion en coordenadas
    function codeAddress() {

        //obtengo la direccion del formulario
        var address = document.getElementById("direccion").value;
        //hago la llamada al geodecoder
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {

        //si el estado de la llamado es OK
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            //centro el mapa en las coordenadas obtenidas
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            //coloco el marcador en dichas coordenadas
            marker.setPosition(results[0].geometry.location);
            //actualizo el formulario     
            updatePosition(results[0].geometry.location);

            //Añado un listener para cuando el markador se termine de arrastrar
            //actualize el formulario con las nuevas coordenadas
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(){
                updatePosition(marker.getPosition());
            });
      } else {
          //si no es OK devuelvo error
          alert("No podemos encontrar la direcci&oacute;n, error: " + status);
      }
    });
  }

  //funcion que simplemente actualiza los campos del formulario
  function updatePosition(latLng)
  {

       jQuery('#lat').val(latLng.lat());
       jQuery('#long').val(latLng.lng());

  }
```

I placed the next code into the funcionts.php file for referencing the js (I doubled checked the page ID and my API Key):

```
add_action('template_redirect','carga_archivos');

function carga_archivos(){

if( is_single(2)) // tu número de post o slug
{
        wp_enqueue_script( 'google-api','http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={MY API KEY}&sensor=true', array( 'jquery' ) );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'google-maps', get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . '/js/google-maps.js', array( 'google-api' ) );
}
```

}

And added to my header.php:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={MY API KEY}&sensor=true"></script>
```

The code of the page is:

```
<form id="google" action="#" name="google"><label>Número de Revista</label>
<input id="numerorevista" type="int" name="numerorevista;" value="0" />
<label>Dirección donde será liberada</label>
<input id="direccion" type="text" name="direccion" />
<button id="pasar">Pasar al mapa</button>
<!-- div donde se dibuja el mapa-->
<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 450px; height: 300px;"></div>
<!--campos ocultos donde guardamos los datos-->
<input id="lat" type="text" name="lat" />
<input id="long" type="text" name="lng" />

</form>
```

I will be very gratefull if someone can help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google has disabled the use pt the Maps API for this application. The key you used is not valid or is not authorized for Google maps JavaScript API.

If you obtained this key you still need to enable the use of the JavaScript API

Go to this link for more info:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial

Comment: Thank you very much I changed the API Key and reactivated the services and all is working fine.